# react native text input different borderBottom ui

Tags: react-native

i have four textInputs that each one has borderBottomWidth:1 and borderBottomColor:'black' but they don't look the same in simulator,
one of them looks thicker than the others

```
        <TextInput
          style={{
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor:"black",
         }}
          value={value}
          onFocus={this.handleFocus}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

is this typo not borderBottomWidh `borderBottomWidth:1`